# How can I join two queries on the same table with python / sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, join, sqlalchemy

What's the right way to join two queries on the same table data in SQLAlchemy?

i.e I have a data class defined something like this:

```
class DataMeasurement(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'DataMeasurement'
    id = Column(Integer, Sequence('data_measurement_id_seq'), primary_key=True)
    data_source = Column(String)
    timestamp = Column(DateTime)
    sensor_output = Column(Float)
```

...and I would like to join the following two queries where there are matching timestamps:

```
q1 = self.session.query(DataMeasurement).filter_by(data_source='Sensor1').order_by(DataMeasurement.timestamp)
q2 = self.session.query(DataMeasurement).filter_by(data_source='Sensor2').order_by(DataMeasurement.timestamp)
# ...and now what?
```

Is there a way to do this simply? ...or am I going about this in a fundamentally flawed way (I'm rather new to SQLAlchemy)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a subquery:

```
subq = self.session.query(DataMeasurement).\
    filter_by(data_source='Sensor1').subquery()
q = self.session.query(
    DataMeasurement.timestamp,
    # Use labels to distinguish between identically named columns.
    # This is optional.
    subq.c.sensor_output.label('output1'),
    DataMeasurement.sensor_output.label('output2')
).filter(
    (DataMeasurement.data_source == 'Sensor2') &
    (DataMeasurement.timestamp == subq.c.timestamp)
)

# Simply get a list of named tuples.
print q.all()
# Or access each column using properties.
for row in q:
    print row.timestamp, row.output1, row.output2
```

You can also get results as `DataMeasurement` objects:

```
subq = self.session.query(DataMeasurement).\
    filter_by(data_source='Sensor1').subquery()
# Use alias to associate mapped class to a subquery.
dmalias = aliased(DataMeasurement, subq)
q = self.session.query(dmalias, DataMeasurement).filter(
    (DataMeasurement.data_source == 'Sensor2') &
    (DataMeasurement.timestamp == dmalias.timestamp)
)

# For each row you get a tuple containing two DataMeasurement objects.
for dm1, dm2 in q:
    print dm1.timestamp, dm1.sensor_output, dm2.sensor_output
```

Comment: That certainly returns the correct information. Just one question, how do I access the attributes of the resulting query? Is there a way to return two `DataMeasurement` objects or do I only get a named tuple for each matching row?

Comment: Yep, you can get results as `DataMeasurement` objects, I'll update my answer to illustrate that.

Comment: How do you access them in the second example (as DataMeasurement objects)? i.e. how do you distinguish between them? 'q...'?

Comment: You get a tuple of two `DataMeasurement` objects for each row. I extended the second example to demonstrate that.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [aliases](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/tutorial.html#using-aliases) to make the relationship between same tables.

Your query might be like

```
adalias1 = aliased(DataMeasurement)
adalias2 = aliased(DataMeasurement)
q1 = self.session.query(DataMeasurement).\
        filter(
               and_(
                    adalias1.data_source in ('Sensor1', 'Sensor2'), 
                    adalias1.timestamp == adalias2.timestamp
                   )
              )
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but looking at the SQL statements generated, it looks like `adalias1.data_source in ('Sensor1', 'Sensor2')` is getting translated into `0`. If I remove the `AND` the query ends with this: `WHERE "DataMeasurement_1".timestamp = "DataMeasurement_2".timestamp` ...but with the and included it looks like this: `WHERE 0 AND "DataMeasurement_1".timestamp = "DataMeasurement_2".timestamp`

Comment: I changed `in adalias1.data_source in ('Sensor1', 'Sensor2')` to `in_(['Sensor1', 'Sensor2'])` which seems to have fixed the `0` into a proper SQL term, but it doesn't appear to be filtering any results out at all now (i.e. the results of the query include other sensors)?